# Is it possible to create a css based gradient on a fixed height scale?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a div that gets resized programmatically and sits inside a wrapper div. I would like the background color of the (inner) div to be a gradient, but with the gradient based on the height of the wrapper div.

For example, the gradient could be something like `background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 0%, green 50%, yellow 80%, orange 90%, red 100%)`

When the inner div is less than 50% of the height of the wrapper div, I want it to be completely green, but if it gets to 70%, it would start to turn yellow at the top, at 80% it starts going orange at the top and if it hit 100% it would have the full gradient. See the codepen below for an example of what I mean in terms of the colors.

The inner div will be resized every 10th of a second or so and will look similar to an audio peak meter.

Is this possible to achieve with pure CSS, or do I need to use javascript? If I use javascript, would it be more performant to have a bunch of css classes and switch them depending on percentage, or color things directly?

I could achieve this with multiple blocks, something like https://codepen.io/octod/pen/vPQLVo (not mine), but ideally I want it to be one continuous block of color with a smooth gradient.

I could also achieve it by keeping the inner div full height and resizing an overlay div, but unfortunately I have a transparent background, so this is not ideal.

EDIT: As requested, this is what I currently have that does not work (it shows the full gradient when the inner div is not the full height). I have simplified it and put css inline for this post.

real snippet: (*Edited by Mister Jojos - this is not representative of my code, but the accepted answer is based on this version, so I have left it like this*)

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1em;
  }
.outer > div {
  width: 100%;
  }
  #inner50 {
  height: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 0%, green 50%, yellow 80%, orange 90%, red 100%);
  }
#inner70 {        /* please set the gradient values */
  height: 70%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 0%, green 50%, yellow 80%, orange 90%, red 100%);
  }
#inner100 {       /* please set the gradient values */
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 0%, green 50%, yellow 80%, orange 90%, red 100%);
  }
```

```html
 
 <!-- result in case 50% --> 
 <div class="outer">  <div id="inner50"></div> </div>

 <!-- result in case 70% --> 
<div class="outer">  <div id="inner70"></div> </div>

 <!-- result in case 100% --> 
<div class="outer">  <div id="inner100"></div> </div>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
// this function is called every 1/10th of a second
function updateMeter(newHeight) {
    getElementById("inner").style.height = newHeight+'px';
}
```

Comment: So we have a div (A) inside a div (B) and the div (A) changes pitch every tenth of a second. div (A) can vary from 50% to 100% of div (B) and change color depending on that height. That's it? what you write seems very confusing to me and my translator gets confused. I have an idea for an answer, but I won't do anything until I clearly understand

Comment: However, did you notice that this platform is NOT a code writing service ? you have to produce a minimal code, at least with the html structure, and your css for some relevant case...

Comment: I can put in the code that I have that changes the height of the inner div, but it's nothing special, and I am not sure it's really relevant. I can also put in the code that I have that works with an overlay (but it's not suitable for a transparent background), but again I'm not sure it's relevant.

The translation doesn't seem to convey the problem very well. If you look at the codepen I linked, that's what I would like, but with a solid block and a smooth gradient instead of many separate blocks.

Comment: a div that changes size on its own is impossible, how can I simulate this kind of action to test the code? I changed your code, please complete it.  and where is the tranceparency ???

Comment: your codePen crashes my machine, and causes me to lose the beginning of the code I had written to answer you. Anyway, I don't want to go and analyze the 150 lines of code that are written there. you have to explain better by yourself

Comment: Temani Afif has answered my question, thanks! (ps. the codepen is not mine and it was only intended to visualize a result similar to what I wanted, not to look at the code)

Comment: Also @MisterJojo - your edited code does not work with the javascript that changes height and does not really make sense for what I am trying to do, which would just be one div that dynamically changes height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply fix the size of the gradient to the size of the outer div:

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.outer>div {
  width: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(0deg, green 0%, green 50%, yellow 80%, orange 90%, red 100%) 
      top/ /* place it on the top */
      100% 400px; /* width=100% height=400px */
}

#inner50 {
  height: 50%;
}

#inner70 {
  height: 70%;
}

#inner100 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- result in case 50% -->
<div class="outer">
  <div id="inner50"></div>
</div>

<!-- result in case 70% -->
<div class="outer">
  <div id="inner70"></div>
</div>

<!-- result in case 100% -->
<div class="outer">
  <div id="inner100"></div>
</div>
```

Also like below:

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 400px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.outer>div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:auto;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(0deg, green 0%, green 50%, yellow 80%, orange 90%, red 100%) 
      bottom/ /* place it on the top */
      100% 400px; /* width=100% height=400px */
}

#inner50 {
  height: 50%;
}

#inner70 {
  height: 70%;
}

#inner100 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- result in case 50% -->
<div class="outer">
  <div id="inner50"></div>
</div>

<!-- result in case 70% -->
<div class="outer">
  <div id="inner70"></div>
</div>

<!-- result in case 100% -->
<div class="outer">
  <div id="inner100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, the gradient vaules changes depending on the height value, but I don't understand the explanation of the PO

Comment: The second example is exactly what I needed (except that the outer div would have a transparent background), thank you!

Comment: Additional note: The actual case only has one div (not three, but my original code snippet was changed by @MisterJojo), however I can use just one of the divs in your answer and change the height dynamically so it fits what I have. I am leaving Mister Jojos' code there otherwise your answer doesn't make sense. Thanks!